# Vue js SPA hosting

Tags: vue.js, build, hosting, single-page-application

Is there a good and easy to understand tutorial on hosting vue.js SPA application. I have currently uploaded the complete project to the server through Filezilla. And I hadn't run `npm run build` prior to hosting the system. Can I run `npm run build` locally and then upload the `dist folder` to the already hosted application. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just run `npm run build` on the client and then upload the dist folder to the server. That's the normal use case, there's usually no reason to move the whole project with all the dependencies to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `npm run build` next upload files from folder `dist` to server. In `dist` folder there will be all files which are required to SPA correct working.